# App returns error "your user photo IMG wrapper is not rendered as a circle yet"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an issue with a challenge I am undertaking: App returns error "your user photo IMG wrapper is not rendered as a circle yet". I have tried and checked most resources but have been left stuck. I don't know if it is a viewport issue or not but my tests keep failing.

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <title>Mini App</title>

    <style>
     body{
        background: lavender;
        margin: 0px;
        overflow: hidden
      }
      *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      
      h2{
        text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2.79em;
        text-transform: Capitalize;
      }
    
 
      div.user-photo{
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        margin: 1em auto;
        background: #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-radius: 100%;
        -webkit-border-radius: 60%;
        -moz-border-radius: 60%;
      }
      
     
    
      div.details{
        font-size: 2.3em;
        margin: 2.5em 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 0.2em;
        display: flex;
        min-height: 6em;
        background: #6200ee;
      }
      
      footer{
        width: calc(100% - 2em);
        z-index: 500;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin: 0 1em;
      }
     
      footer button.mdc-icon-button{
        margin: 0.5em;
        background-color: #573594;
      }
      
       img{
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        display: block;

      }
      
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <header>
      <h2>Ibu Omenka Eric</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="user-photo mdc-elevation--z3" >
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt =""/>
    </div>
    
    <div class ="details mdc-elevation--z3"></div>
    <div class ="messages"></div>
    
    <footer>
      <button id = "btn-address" 
              class="mdc-icon-button small material-icons" style="color: white;"><i> home</i></button>
      <button id = "btn-phone"  
              class="mdc-icon-button small material-icons" style="color: white;"><i>phone</i></button>
      <button id = "btn-birthdate"  
              class="mdc-icon-button small material-icons" style="color: white;"><i>date_range</i></button>
    </footer>
    
    <script>

      
      const notify = (msg) => {
        const toastr = document.querySelector('.messages');
        if(!toastr) return;
        
        toastr.textContent = msg;
        if(!toastr.classList.contains('on')) {
          toastr.classList.add('on');
        }
      };
      
      const clearNotice = () => {
        const toastr = document.querySelector('.messages');
        if(!toastr) return;
        
        toastr.textContent = '';
        toastr.classList.remove('on');
      };
      
      const displayUserPhotoAndName = (data) => {
        if(!data) return;
        
        // add your code here

        clearNotice();
      };
            
      const getAUserProfile = () => {
        const api = 'https://randomuser.me/api/';
        
        // make API call here
        
        notify(`requesting profile data ...`);
      };
      
      const startApp = () => {
        // invoke the getAUserProfile here
      };

      startApp();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I cannot figure out where the error is in the code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be specific in your issue, 'how to code' type questions are discouraged.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
    div .user-photo {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 1em auto;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. What was the mistake and how does your answer fix that?

Comment: Although this can be the correct answer, please elaborate on your solution.